# Universal Product Code challenge

Tags: c, operators

I am curious how to correctly use `%d` in the C language. I am currently taking a course in C programming and we were given a small challenge to edit a code from the textbook (C Programming A Modern Approach, K. N. KING). 
The goal was to edit the code from three inputs of the bar code:

- the 1st digit, the 5th, and the 5th to last into one single input, or
- all 11 digits at once.

In the way the text explains the operator, I believe that `%1d` allows the entered integers to be individually assigned to the corresponding variable.
Below is the edited code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    /* 11 integers that come from the bar code of the product, 
    then 2 intermediate variables for calulation, and lastly the final answer.*/

    int d, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, first_sum, second_sum, total;    

    printf("Enter the 11 digit Universal Product Code: ");
    scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &d, &i1, &i2, &i3, &i4, &i5, &j1, &j2, &j3, &j4, &j5);

    // The steps for each calculation from the textbook.
    first_sum = d + i2 + i4 + j1 + j3 + j5;
    second_sum = i1 + i3 + i5 + j2 + j4;
    total = 3 * first_sum + second_sum;

    // Prints check digit for given product code.
    printf("Check Digit: %d\n", 9 - ((total-1) % 10));
    return 0;
}
```

---

However when I run the program (same trouble with the original program) it does not accept the 11 digit input as 11 separate numbers, only as one large number. Instead it still requires enter to be hit after each integer. Can integers be read and assigned to variables this way?

Comment: read it as a string, then tokenize it with strtok

Comment: never use `strtok`.  It is hopelessly broken.

Comment: read as a string and pick out each char in turn (srtr[0],str[1], str[2],...)

Comment: @abelenky - _never use strtok. It is hopelessly broken_  - at least cite something.  `strtok()` is ***not*** _hopelessly_ broken.  The issue cited by some people recently is it's lack of thread safety.  But it does not purport thread safety.  So, what's the issue?

Comment: 1) Either your complier is broke or the events described are not so.  2) What is the return value from `scanf()`  and what is the value from `d`?

Comment: @ryyker:  It is not a thread-safety issue.  That is a very common misconception.  But it is easy to write a single-threaded program where strtok still does not work properly.  Such a program is too long for a comment, but I may write and post one later.

Comment: @ryyker: Well, at least `strtok()` should be frowned upon. If you look at its man page, there is a "Bugs" section that lists a few reasons that will almost always discourage it use, the most important, IMHO, being that it modifies the string it gets (which cannot be constant, as such). As mentioned by @ablenky, thread-safety is a non-issue if you use the `strtok_r()` variant. But apart from that, what delimiter would you pass it in this case?

Comment: @SukkoPera - Referencing ***[this page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)***, Calling the items listed under ***Bugs*** _"Bugs"_ is a stretch. (***Notes:*** would be a better title)  `strtok()` continues to be very useful for parsing files containing normal text, using normal delimiters.  It produces repeatable, accurate, consistent results when abiding by its prototype, and the rules in the man page. Agreed, `strtok()` is not appropriate for answering this post, but neither is understating it's usefulness in general.  Calling it _hopelessly broken_ is simply not accurate.  Just an opinion.

Comment: @ryyker:  [Detailed example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588170/is-strtok-broken-or-just-tricky/28588171) showing why `strtok` is always broken, even in a single-threaded program, and why `strtok_r` is always needed.

Comment: @abelenky - Yes, thanks - saw it already.   Chose not to weigh in.  But since you bring it up, and If I can be candid, I think you have overstated issues with `strtok()`. You have put a magnifying glass on a function to point out behaviors you do not agree with.   I have personally used `strtok()`, when and where appropriate, for years.  When I follow the rules, I've never had a problem.  In every example you've shown, the problems occurs when the boundaries of `strtok()` spec. have been violated.

Comment: As I see it, the boundaries of the strtok spec violate the boundaries of the C-language specification.  strtok should not be a C-function, because it creates new limitations and restrictions above and beyond the C-language.  As a component of the Standard Library, `strtok` certainly can and should be held to the highest standards.

Answer (score 1):

Given the code below, if you type "123" and then press enter, it will print "1 2 3".

```
int main( void )
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf( "Enter a three digit number\n" );
    if ( scanf( "%1d%1d%1d", &a, &b, &c ) != 3 )
        printf( "hey!!!\n" );
    else
        printf( "%d %d %d\n", a, b, c );
}
```

Which is to say that the `%1d` will read one digit at a time.

---

The following example comes from section 7.21.6.2 of the draft C11 specification

```
EXAMPLE 2 The call:
    #include <stdio.h>
    /* ... */
    int i; float x; char name[50];
    fscanf(stdin, "%2d%f%*d %[0123456789]", &i, &x, name);

with input:
    56789 0123 56a72
will assign to i the value 56 and to x the value 789.0, will skip 0123,
and will assign to name the sequence 56\0. The next character read from 
the input stream will be a.
```

---

That's the way it's always been, so if your compiler doesn't do that, you need to get a new compiler.

Comment: I guess it depends on the libc implementation... Which one did you test?

Comment: @SukkoPera: It *should* always work, unless I'm missing something. OP, can you test this code with your implementation? Maybe it's some weird bug or something.

Comment: OK, thanks for the C11 Draft reference. Now we know that this is standard-mandated behaviour, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no. The %d tag will grab the largest integer that it can, not just a single digit unless there is some sort of delimiting space in the string.

The general way to solve this would be to read the input as a string, then tokenize the input using strtok or the like.

However, since in C strings are just character arrays, you can also just iterate through a loop and call on string[0], string[1], and so on, and turn each of those into an integer separately as long as you know the length of the input beforehand, which given your explanation it sounds like you do.

Comment: Not the down voter - but regarding _then tokenize the input using strtok_:  what delimiter would you tokenize on using `strtok()`.  (your third paragraph I think is a reasonable approach)

Comment: I was the downvoter: *The %d tag will grab the largest integer that it can, not just a single digit unless there is some sort of delimiting space in the string.* is an inherently wrong statement, as demonstrated in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work in gcc comliler. 
But,as it's not working, you should get the 11 digit number into a character array i.e. string and then iterate through the array while converting each character to its corresponding integer value. You can get the value by just calculating `array[i]-'0'` i.e `d = array[0]-'0'` and `i1 = array[1]-'0'` etc. in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just tested the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int n, x, y, z;

    n = sscanf ("1234567890", "%1d%1d%1d", &x, &y, &z);

    printf ("Found %d items: %d, %d and %d\n", n, x, y, z);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it under Slackware Linux, with the stock GCC and glibc. It outputs:

> Found 3 items: 1, 2 and 3

So, it seems it should work the way you would like it to, but I'm not sure if this is actually standard behaviour or rather a GCC extension.

An alternative would be reading one character at a time with `%1c` and then converting that to the corresponding integer with `atoi()` or simply subtracting `'0'` from it, if you must/want to absolutely use `scanf()` that way. Otherwise what I would do is reading the whole string with `%s` and then iterating on the single characters, which is very easy in C, as a string is simply an array of characters.