# c how to cut of the first x words of a string?

Tags: c

I have a char array:

```
char tmp[2048];
```

I want to cut of the first x words of tmp. I define a word as a sequence of characters that does not include whitespaces. I tried something like this (should cut of the first 3 words):

```
sscanf(tmp, "%*s %*s %*s %s", tmp);
```

My problem is, that '%s' stops at the first whitespace it finds. I want the new string to end at the end of the old string, not at the first whitespace.

I'm also open for other suggestions how to cut of the first x words of a string. I define a word as a sequence of characters that doesn't contain whitespaces.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `std::string`, which allows you to do all of this with 2 or 3 lines of code, no bugs, no memory leaks and full exception safety? Why would you want to deal with raw dynamic arrays yourself?

Comment: What is the return value of sscanf in your code? sscanf returns the number of items in the argument list which were filled.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `sscanf` and not `strcpy` or `memcpy`? It seems you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: What's the point of using c++ then? Wrong tool indeed.

Comment: can't just change language for 1 short part of a big project

Comment: I would suggest changing the tag to C; the only C++ you're using here is `new`.

Comment: If by "compatibility", you mean "compatibility with C", then you cannot use `new` and `delete` either, mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough implementation:

```
const char* TrimWords(const char* input, int nWords)
{
    while (nWords)
    {
        if (!isspace(*input) && isspace(*(input + 1)))
        {
            nWords--;
        }
        input++;
    }
    return input;
}
```

---

```
TrimWords("One Two Three Four Five", 3);
// returns " Four Five" after the first 3 words are trimmed.
```

Detailed input validation and error checking is left to the OP.
This is just a good starting point.

Comment: Hmm, I like this much better than my possible solution.

Comment: nice, i have not much knowledge of char arrays in c, thanks for that starting point, i'll be able to customize this for my needs

Comment: would suggest to change your condition to switch to the next word to '(isspace(*input) && !isspace(*(input + 1)))'

Answer (score 0):

use `strncpy(tmp, n, tmp+m);` where m and n are ints

```
char tmp[20] = "abcdef";

strncpy(tmp, tmp + 3, 2);
```

for exmaple: code above will result in decdef

Comment: made my question more clear, i want to cut of the first x words of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok` to tokenize strings by whitespace. Something similar to this could do what you're trying to achieve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Number of words to trim
    const int numWords = 2;

    char tmp[1024];
    char buffer[1024];
    sprintf(tmp, "this  is a\tsentence.");

    strcpy(buffer, tmp);

    char* token = strtok(buffer, " \t");
    for (int i = 0; i < numWords && token; i++) {
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }

    if (token) {
        size_t len = 1024 - (token - buffer);
        memmove(tmp, tmp + (token - buffer), len);
    }
    else {
        memset(tmp, '\0', 1024);
    }

    // Prints "a    sentence."
    printf("%s", tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the use of `strtok` is tricky at best. I would suggest using an approach similar to that of abelenky's answer.

Comment: Never, never use `strtok`. [***Link***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588170/is-strtok-broken-or-just-tricky/28588171?noredirect=1#comment45499462_28588171)

Comment: @abelenky Interesting; I'm aware of many dangerous C functions, but I wasn't aware of this peculiarity, as I've strayed pretty far away from C and much more toward C++.