# How does strtok() for a token extracted with strtok() works in C?

Tags: c, strtok

Consider the following code for tokenizing the string at space characters,

```
int main()
{
    char L[100];
    fgets(L, 100, stdin);

    for(char* token = strtok(L, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " ")){
        char L1[10];
        strcpy(L1, token);

        printf("%s", L1);
    }
}
```

When the input is given as,

```
60@2 120@3
```

It eventually prints out as expected,

```
60@2120@3
```

Now, I would like to tokenize the string again that contains "@" character,
Say, I wanna tokenize 60@2 and 120@3 with "@" character.

So, I started with the following code,

```
int main()
{
    char L[100];
    fgets(L, 100, stdin);

    for(char* token = strtok(L, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " ")){
        char L1[10];
        strcpy(L1, token);

        printf("%s", L1);

        char* token2 = strtok(L1, "@"); // extra line 1
        printf("%s", token2);           // extra line 2
    }
}
```

However for the same input,

```
60@2 120@3
```

The output generated was,

```
60@26022
```

Can you explain what is happening in the second case?

Comment: Nested uses of strtok do not work. Use strtok_r on POSIX or strtok_s on Windows instead. The inner strtok screws up the outer.  There are other questions which cover this; it is a duplicate

Comment: however, I copy the token inside the for() loop to another variable so that the original remains intact.

Comment: You can't copy the hidden state.  That hidden state is is exposed in the interface to the alternatives.

Comment: Strtok is broken for exactly this reason. 
 You cannot call `strtok` in a nested fashion yourself; you cannot call any other function that might possibly call `strtok` either: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588170/is-strtok-broken-or-just-tricky